# C++ even and odd number checking with bigger values

Tags: c++

By using this little piece of code, i was finding even and odd numbers, but my curiosity grew when i enter number 8888888888(10 times) and it give me answer odd at the same time i again enter number 88888888(9 times) and it give me even number. Any one having idea about it.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a%2==0){
        cout<<"even";
    }else{
        cout<<"odd";
    }
}
```

I check this code on Dev C++ compiler. Thank you

Comment: `8888888888` is larger than what a standard `int` can hold so I bet you are overflowing.

Comment: What did you expect? Why?

Comment: Try printing out the number you enter.

Comment: what is expect it should give even number for both situations whether i enter 10 times 8 or 9 time 8

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Your code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) you shouldn't expect anything except bizarre amounts of strange weirdness.

Comment: just before your `if(a%2==0)` add a `cout << a << endl;`  and see if your a is really 8888888888.

Comment: Thank you @Eddge i got your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built-in numeric types have a limited range of values they can represent. `8888888888` is beyond the range of `int` on your platform. See [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `long` keyword instead of `int` for large numbers: i.e. `long a;`.

Comment: Note that on some (many) platforms/compilers, the `long` type is the same size as the `int` type. It would be better to use `long long int` or one of the fixed-size types, like `int64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others are saying, the standard built-in types are not big enough for what you are trying to do.

What i reccomend you to do is to build a class in which you can store big numbers. The easyest way to do this (if you don't really care about memory usage) is to store big numbers as seperate digits in an array.

It's even easyer if you only want to know if the number is even or odd:
if your input is a string you could just split of the last character and change it to an integer. This integer says everything about if the whole number is even or odd.

I hope this helps.

regards, Harm

Comment: There is nothing in the question that suggests a need for a big integer type.

Comment: The problem is that the number the op is inputting causes an overflow. The solution to this is a bigger integer type. If you want it to work with all integers this would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**In case of C++**
The n1 and n2 are the string

```
 if((n1[n1.size()-1] * n2[n2.size()-1]) % 2 == 0){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```